# How to enable -mno-outline-atomics AArch64 flag?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, arm64

I've been trying to cross compile an open source library for AArch64.
When I run an executable linking against this library on a Raspberry Pi 4 (running a 64-bit OS), I get an Illegal Instruction error.

I created a github issue and the library developer suggested I enable the `-mno-outline-atomics` compiler flag (more details on the github issue [here](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/issues/2409)). More details on the flag itself can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html).

So I edited the aarch64 cmake toolchain file (found [here](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/blob/master/toolchains/aarch64-linux-gnu.toolchain.cmake)) to include the following:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-march=armv8-a -mno-outline-atomics")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-march=armv8-a -mno-outline-atomics")
```

However, when I try to compile the library, I get the following error messages:

```
-- CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = /home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/toolchains/aarch64-linux-gnu.toolchain.cmake
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/build_aarch64/install
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/build_aarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_65def/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/build_aarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc   -march=armv8-a -mno-outline-atomics    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/build_aarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-outline-atomics’; did you mean ‘-fno-inline-atomics’?
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/build.make:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_65def.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cyrus/work/c-sdks/3rd_party_libs/ncnn/build_aarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:138: recipe for target 'cmTC_65def/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_65def/fast] Error 2
```

Why is the compiler complaining about this: `unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-outline-atomics’`?

How can I properly enable the flag using CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outline-atomic feature was added with gcc 9.4.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
```

Clearly, your compiler is too old and does not support it.

Comment: That would make sense. How would I got about installing  `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` 9.4 cross compiler on Ubuntu?

Comment: @cyrusbehr: I would strongly suggest you to get it from [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).